# How to iterate through all elements of set C++

Tags: c++

[UPDATE: My problem is solved! Lots of thanks to Mike Seymour and Niall and all you guys!]

My code has errors in the for loop and I do not know how to fix it :(

```
MyClass::ITECH7603Class(set<Student>* students) {
    /* Initialize dynamically the group field */
    group = new map<string, Student>();

    for (set<Student>::iterator it = students->begin(); it != students->end(); it++) {
        addStudent(it);
    }
}

void MyClass::addStudent(Student* studentPtr) {
    string fullName = studentPtr->getName() + " " + studentPtr->getSurname();
    group->insert(pair<string, Student>(fullName, *studentPtr));
}
```

So the main idea is to loop through all students in the set, and add each student into a map group. Any help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you really want to copy `Student` into different containers ?

Comment: Thanks to your comments, the prototype of addStudent and the constructor of MyClass couldn't be changed and must be kept as they are. I think the errors lie in the for loop, but I don't know how to fix it, tried so many ways but still got compile errors.

Comment: are you sure you don't have `MyClass::ITECH7603Class(set<Student*> students)` instead? A pointer to a set of students is quite an exotic object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addStudent` takes a pointer, while `it` is an iterator, so can't be passed directly.

You should change `addStudent` to take either a value or a pointer/reference to `const`:

```
// option 1
void addStudent(Student);
addStudent(*it);

// option 2
void addStudent(Student const &);
addStudent(*it);

// option 3
void addStudent(Student const *);
addStudent(&*it);
```

If, as you say in a comment, you must leave it taking a mutable pointer, then you'll need some grotesquery to deal with the fact that elements of the set are immutable:

```
// nasty option
addStudent(const_cast<Student*>(&*it));

// slightly less nasty option
Student copy = *it;
addStudent(&copy);
```

Beware that the first option will give undefined behaviour if the function uses the dodgy pointer to make any modification to the `Student` object stored in the set. The second makes a temporary copy, which can be modified without breaking the set. This is fine as long as `addStudent` only stores a copy of the object passed to it, not the pointer itself, which will become invalid when `copy` is destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (set<Student>::iterator it = students->begin; it != students->end; it++) {
    addStudent(it);
}
```

should be:

```
for (set<Student>::iterator it = students->begin(); it != students->end(); it++) {
                                               //^^                   //^^
    addStudent(it);
}
```

Comment: That's one problem. Also, the argument type is wrong for `addStudent`.

Comment: The argument type of addStudent is fixed and couldn't be changed, I have to follow it.

Comment: @user3454295: In that case, you'd have to change the call to something grotesque like `addStudent(const_cast<Student*>(&*it))`, since elements of a set are `const` and the function requires a non-const pointer. But you really should change the function to take its argument by value or `const` reference, and call it as `addStudent(*it)`.

Comment: Why not use `auto`, or range-for?

Comment: Anyway, do you mind to explain to me what is the meaning of &*it? And why we have to put const_cast<Student*> but not const_cast<Student>. Well these pointers stuff are really confusing :(

Comment: @user3454295: Yes, pointer abuse can be confusing, which is why you really shouldn't be using pointers here. `*` dereferences the iterator to access the object it refers to; `&` takes the address to get a pointer (`const Student *`, since set elements are `const`); `const_cast` removes the `const` to give `Student*` to satisfy the evil function that you insist you can't fix. See my answer to learn why that's a very bad idea, and to see a slightly less horrible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In c++11 you can use [range for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) sytax:

```
for (const auto &student : *students)
{
    addStudent(it);
}
```

Then change addStudent function signature to accept reference:

```
void MyClass::addStudent(const Student &student) {
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've gotten answers that "fix" your code to the extent of compiling and producing results that you apparently find acceptable, I don't find them very satisfying in terms of code style. I would do this job rather differently. In particular, my code to do this wouldn't have a single (explicit) loop. If I needed to do approximately what you're asking for, I'd probably use code something like this:

```
std::pair<std::string, Student> make_mappable(Student &stud) { 
    return std::make_pair(stud.getName() + " " + stud.getSurName(), stud);
}

std::map<std::string, Student> gen_map(std::set<Student> const &input) { 
    std::map<std::string, Student> ret;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                   std::inserter(ret, ret.end()), 
                   make_mappable);
    return ret;
}
```

There definitely would *not* be any `new` in sight, nor would there be any passing a pointer to a `Student`.

OTOH, since the data you're using as the key for your `map` is data that's already in the items in the set, it may more convenient all around to continue to use a set, and just specify a comparison function based on the student's name:

```
struct by_given_name {
    bool operator()(Student const &a, Student const &b) const { 
        if (a.getName() < b.getName())
            return true;
        if (b.getName() < a.getName())
            return false;
        return a.getSurName() < b.getSurName();
    }
};

std::set<Student, by_given_name> xform(std::set<Student> const &in) { 
    return std::set<Student, by_given_name>{in.begin(), in.end()};
}
```

For what its worth, a [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/tPIzPT) of the latter.

Whether the latter is practical will typically depend on one other factor though: your ability to create a `Student` from only a name/surname. If you can't do that, searching by name will be inconvenient (at best), so you'd want to use a map.

I realize this probably isn't much (if any) help in completely what's apparently home-work for a class--but even if your class prevents you from actually *turning in* decent code, it seems worthwhile to me to at least try to learn to *write* decent code in addition to what it requires. If you do pass the class and get a job writing code, you'd probably rather your coworkers didn't want to hurt you.